# NiFi KafkaConsumer not reading Kafka Topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I want to be fetching data from a Python Kafka producer, but the processor is not reading the messages from the topic. I tested the producer on a consumer and it works.I'm using Kafka version 3.3, and KafkaConsumer 2.6.

Python producer

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import json

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9093')

json_data = {"ID": "AS78Z4", "name": "Jhon", "birthdate": "12-12-2001", "balance": "78745.0"}
message_bytes = json.dumps(json_data).encode('utf-8')
producer.send('test', message_bytes)
producer.close()
```

KafkaProcessor config:
[image]